# .each() not initiating click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I'm trying to iterate over li's in a ul using the jquery .each() method but the click function is not being initiated.

**Basic HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="product-list">
      <ul class="list-inline">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is populated on pageload with the following jquery function

**JQUERY**

```
productLoad: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.greens.length; i++) {
        $(".product-list ul").append("<li><div class='product'><p> " + state.greens[i].name + " </p></div></li>");
    }
},
```

productLoad is part of a larger object called display and is initiated by display.productLoad();

I'd trying to write a function that calls another function called display.arrange(arg) which causes the page to display a lot of information about the corresponding object in state.greens.

I'm trying to use jquery's .each method in the following way:

**JQuery**

```
$(".product-list > li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        display.arrange(index);
    })
});
```

The idea is that I add an li for each object in state.greens with productLoad, and then use .each to initiate a function that references each li's corresponding place in state.greens to display information about it.

However, when I click on the li's nothing happens at all, and there are no error messages in the console that correspond to that function so I don't think the click handler is being called.

You can see a working example of what I have on this page:  [Click to go to page](http://www.healthkismet.com/superfood-picker/index_2.html)

Scroll down to where it says "Click On A Product To Go To Its Detail Page" and you'll see the ul with each of the stylized li's that represent each product in state.greens.

Comment: The [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selects "all *direct* child elements", but your `<li>` elements are not *direct* children of `.product-list`.

Comment: @showdev - you're right.  I added a class to the actual ul and changed the jquery object to ("ul class > li").each(function(index).......and it worked just fine.  If you turn this into an actual answer I'll upvote and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your `HTML` code, your CSS selector is wrong. Consider that `>` is used for get immediate children, then your CSS should start selecting the `UL` tag in order to get all its `LI` children

Change:

```
$(".product-list > li")....
```

By:

```
$("ul.list-inline > li")...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".list-inline").on("click", ">li", function(){
    display.arrange($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: yup... I also think so... :)

Comment: A little explanation of the problem and your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you're creating (ie, appending) your `<li>`s using jQuery. That is, they're not in your initial DOM when the page loads. So you need to use [jQuery's ".on"](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the click event. I'm also not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but I don't think that needs to be in an `.each`...you should be able to do the following and just use `this`:

Try switching out your jQuery from this:

```
$(".product-list > li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        display.arrange(index);
    })
});
```

to this:

```
$(".product-list").on("click", "li", function(index) {
    // Run functions, mo' jQuery, etc.
});
```

That should get your click to register. From there, what you run inside the `.on("click")` is up to you.